# Promises making API calls in JavaScript with async/await syntax

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, axios

Trying to get a better grasp on Promises with async/await syntax. .then().catch() feels more straightforward with the added visual cues and structure.
Do these two async/await functions make any logical sense for making multiple API calls and acting on the data once they're resolved?
The goal is to have a function that takes the url, number of additional pages and returns data from all calls in one output. It works but is slow enough to lead me to believe its pretty inefficient. (I'm sure the nested loops dont help)

```
async function getData(url, numOfPages) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url)
    const { results, next: nextUrl } = response.data

    const nextPages = await getNextPages(nextUrl, numOfPages)

    const finalData = results.concat(nextPages)

    finalData.forEach(data => console.log(data.name))
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
getData('https://swapi.dev/api/planets/', 3)


async function getNextPages(nextUrl, numOfPages) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(nextUrl)
    const data = response.data.results.map(res => res)

    let nextPage = response.data.next

    for (let i = 1; i < numOfPages; i++) {
      let response = await axios.get(nextUrl)
      let results = response.data.results
      nextPage = response.data.next

      for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        data.push(results[i])
      }
    }
    return data
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: There's different syntax you could use to write this, but nothing that would make a noticeable difference in speed. The slowness is due to the API latency. What you have here is fine.

Comment: @Adam Yea they work. I guess I just need to dive deeper into Promises and API calls in general because the route I took of making an initial call for the first URL in both functions and then acting on additional pages with further calls seems avoidable, particularly in the getNextPages function. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: It's now most likely a UX problem that you're describing, you're code is fine. Consider just getting the first page, doing whatever you need to do with the results of the call (e.g. display it to the user) and requesting subsequent pages after that first work is done.

Comment: What is happening is you are resolving each api call one at a time.
You can fire them off all at once and resolve an array of promises instead

Comment: @DanielDuong Thanks that actually made a huge difference in log time just by taking "await" out of the calls and moving it to a separate variable. I'll have to look more into sequential vs parallel calls. This isnt for a real project which is why there are no handlers or anything. I just wanted to play around with calls a little more.